# How to deactivate or define for all cases v-if in v-for in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, vuetify.js, v-for

I have a `v-for` in which I use `v-if`. If variable `choice` has value "a", display only elements with `label.type` is "a". If "b" display elements with `label.type` is "b". How can I make v-if display everything, if, for example `choice` has value "c"? Is it possible to deactivate `v-if` or something? Is there an easier way to do this?

```
<v-card v-for="label in labels" v-bind:item="label" v-bind:key="label._id">
  <div v-if="label.type === filter> {{ label.key }}
  </div>
</v-card>
```

```
  computed: {
    filter() {
      let filter= this.choice === "a"? "a" : "b";
      return filter;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just evaluate your if in a method, then you can add all the additional logic you need to.

```
methods: {
  shouldDisplayLabel(type) {
    // if choice is c, display everything
    if(this.choice === 'c') return true;

    // check if choice matches the label type
    return this.choice === type;
  }
}
```

Then your template could look like this:

```
<v-card v-for="label in labels" v-bind:item="label" v-bind:key="label._id">
  <div v-if="shouldDisplayLabel(label.type)"> {{ label.key }}
  </div>
</v-card>
```